# How to capture optional group and replace if not matched?

Tags: regex, replace, grouping

I have this situation where the user might enter a URL with or without `http(s)://`. I would like to have it if it's there otherwise add `http://` myself. I have the below regex pattern:

Regex: `\[url\](?:https?\:\/\/)?(.*?)\[\/url\]` Replacement: `<a href="$1">$1</a>`

which makes this

```
[url]http://blog.sanspace.in[/url]
[url]https://blog.sanspace.in[/url]
[url]blog.sanspace.in[/url]
[url]blog.sanspace.in/scraperwiki[/url]
[url]www.sanspace.in[/url]
```

into this

```
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in">http://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in">http://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in">http://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in/scraperwiki">http://blog.sanspace.in/scraperwiki</a>
<a href="http://www.sanspace.in">http://www.sanspace.in</a>
```

Now, what I would like is to make it like this. (use http(s) if available. otherwise, http)

```
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in">http://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="https://blog.sanspace.in">https://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in">http://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in/scraperwiki">http://blog.sanspace.in/scraperwiki</a>
<a href="http://www.sanspace.in">http://www.sanspace.in</a>
```

I tried adding the `http(s)` as a group.

Regex: `\[url\](https?\:\/\/)?(.*?)\[\/url\]` Replacement: `<a href="$1$2">$1$2</a>`

ut, in that case the replacement order `$1` and `$2` are different. If user added `http` it becomes `$1` otherwise, URL becomes `$1`.

```
<a href="http://blog.sanspace.in">http://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="https://blog.sanspace.in">https://blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="blog.sanspace.in">blog.sanspace.in</a>
<a href="blog.sanspace.in/scraperwiki">blog.sanspace.in/scraperwiki</a>
<a href="www.sanspace.in">www.sanspace.in</a>
```

Note the last 3 URLs. Here I have to add `http` but only if I know there wasn't a user added `http`. I'm not sure how to achieve my goal.

I'm testing this problem here. http://regexr.com?3711a

Comment: Which language/tool for this regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following regex:

**Match :** `\[url\](?:http(s)?\:\/\/)?(.*?)\[\/url\]`

**Replace :** `<a href="http$1://$2">http$1://$2</a>`

[regexr demo](http://regexr.com?3711j)

Since you are willing to insert `http://` if it's not present in original string, the idea here is not capture it even if it's present. Instead capture only optional `s` indicating secure http into `$1`.

Comment: Works great. Nice idea. Why I don't think like this?? :)